Subspaces dimension of two 4D planes intersection
Consider vector $\mathbf{v} = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$.
Let $*$ is operation which convert vector $v$ to the vector $\mathbf{v}^* = \left(\dfrac{1}{v_1}, \dfrac{1}{v_2}, \dfrac{1}{v_3}, \dfrac{1}{v_4} \right)$.
So, $<\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{v}^* > = 4.$
Also consider vector $\mathbf{n} = (n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4)$ and planes $A$ and $B$:
$$
A = \{ \mathbf{v} \; | <\mathbf{n}, \mathbf{v}> = 0 \}, \qquad B = \{ \mathbf{v} \; | <\mathbf{n}, \mathbf{v}^*> = 0 \}.
$$
I'm trying to find the total dimension of linear subspaces lying in the intersection.
I know that for finite-dimension $U, W \subset V$
$$
dim(U + W) = dim(U) + dim(W) - dim(U \cap W).
$$
But I can't realised the next step. Maybe due to I can't find the intersection of two planes $A$ and $B$.

Welcome to MSE! <> (i) The notation for $A$ and $B$ uses $\mathbf{n}$ as the normal vector, while $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are used to denote normal vectors in one place and elements of $A$ and $B$ in another. (ii) Do you know how to find the dimensions of $A$ and $B$ individually? (The term planes suggests you're thinking they're $2$-dimensional, which they are not.)

@AndrewD.HwangThank you! (i) I updated OP. I hope it's more clear now.  (ii) I think that I know equation for $A$ (also $B$):
$$
n_1 v_1 + n_2 v_2 + n_3 v_3 + n_4 v_4 = 0.
$$
So, I know coordinates of $\mathbf{n}$. Thus, $v_1, \dots, v_4$ is basis, therefore $dim(A) = 4$.

@AndrewD.Hwang Not sure that I tagged you correctly.
